# Artifact upload - Business Central v 7.73.0.Final

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

Trying to upload pojo jar artifact through the admin->artifacts screen.  I have 3 jars to upload.  2 have uploaded without issue.  The 3rd does not upload.  The server logs show:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.mydomain:product-base:jar:1.0 from/to global-m2-repo (file:/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/repositories/kie/global/): /tmp/com.mydomain-product-base-1.0-0.08643717118930383.jar.tmp.tmp (No such file or directory)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:317)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:245)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:420)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.repositories.FileSystemArtifactRepository.deploy(FileSystemArtifactRepository.java:172)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.mydomain:product-base:jar:1.0 from/to global-m2-repo (file:/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/repositories/kie/global/): /tmp/com.mydomain-product-base-1.0-0.08643717118930383.jar.tmp.tmp (No such file or directory)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.put(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:274)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:311)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/com.mydomain-product-base-1.0-0.08643717118930383.jar.tmp.tmp (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.PutTask.newInputStream(PutTask.java:56)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.utilPut(AbstractTransporter.java:147)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.transport.file.FileTransporter.implPut(FileTransporter.java:85)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.put(AbstractTransporter.java:117)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$PutTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:510)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    ... 97 more
```

If I look on the server in the `/tmp` folder there is a file with the name it is looking for but it does not have the 2nd `.tmp` on the end of it.

Is this a bug in the workbench or in my pojo jar?  The pojo jar is being used without issue in a previous very old version of drools guvnor.

Is there a way to put the pojo jar into the repository without going through the UI?

Comment: If it doesn't have the second `.tmp`, then it _doesn't_ have the file with the name it's looking for ... ^_^

Comment: Does it work if you delete the `.tmp` temporary file that you say is present in your tmp directory?

Comment: No.  I also can't rename the file to have the second .tmp because the file is time stamped when the process runs.

Comment: I was able to get it to load by manually adding the pom.xml info into the jar instead of having the workbench prompt me for it.  Not a great way to do it but it works.

Comment: No I"m asking if you delete the pre-existing .tmp file, does it help. The idea being that it's trying to create a .tmp.tmp because .tmp already exists, and it gets confused.